# add my own property to EF designer

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I using vs2010 and  the built-in  EF designer against SQL server Compact 4.0 local database that in my project. ( design-first)

I tried to add (through the designer) to one of the entities a new property that doesn't exist in the DB (nor planed to) by: add-new scalar property.... , but when i was tring to validate it, i got an error:

> property "x" is not map

my question:

can i add my own properties to the schema through the designer. and that properties won't be exist in the underline DB.(I thought i could)?
if I can, how?

Comment: Non Db properties you can add by creating a partial class for that entity and adding your props there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add non db fields to your entity by creating a partial class of that entity with the required properties.  These won't be used for the ORM.

```
public partial class MyEntity {

    public string StringStatusCode { get;set;}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it is strange though that i can't do it from the designer...

Comment: I can only presume it's because EF is and ORM framework, so non-db mappable fields don't belong in the designer.... me thinks